# Layout Design Ideas

Tags: android

I am not sure the best way to ask this question.
I am new to Android development and want to know what is the best way to accomplish what I need, for example a combination of SurfaceViews, or just a View what container should they be a child of… things like that.  I am developing this on the XOOM Tablet... but it needs to work on all Honeycomb Android tablets.

[I have a sample screen prototype, but I don't have a high enough reputation to post it.]

Here is what I am looking for.  The main Activity that is going to be featured on this app needs to display 16 bitmaps in a 4x4 grid.  This grid needs to take up half or a little more that half of the left side of the screen.  The remaining portion of the screen will just have TextViews, Buttons, and other typical controls.

The catch is I want to be able to double click on one of these 16 images and have it animate to take up the entire space of the 16… effectively hiding the rest behind it as it comes to the foreground.  Then the user can double click on it again to animate back into its position in the grid.

Also I am going to be receiving data from a server over the wifi connection that might tell me I need to draw something on top of the bitmap.  For example my bitmaps are pictures of a football game and I may need to draw a new score or an icon or something on top of a game.  So I was thinking I could use 16 SurfaceViews, one for each game, but I tried ScaleAnimation and although the SurfaceView does resize, the bitmap drawn on it does not, and if I ask it what its size is or scaleX is after the ScaleAnimation is complete it tells me the original size, not the scaled size.  So that didn’t work for me.

I am open to ideas on how to lay this out and what combination of Views, or whatever would help me get this thing working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are targeting honeycomb or later you can take the most simple route which is using standard views. Just make sure to activate hardware acceleration in your manifest.
As you already discovered SurfaceViews cannot easily be animated using the standard android animation framework.

So for the left part of the screen use a GridView / nested LinearViews or custom Layout to get your 4x4 matrix. Each ChildView could then be  me made up of a FrameLayout containing an imageview and a number of textviews on top of the imageView. This will guarantee that you are making the most of what the framework gives you reducing development time and maximizing flexibility.
Be sure to read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) especially the part about layers to speed up animations. Also make sure to use the cool new [animation framework](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html)

Comment: I ended up using the GridView and it contains 16 FrameLayouts each with a CustomImageView (which extends ImageView) and a TextView. The only thing I cannot get to work right now is the animation.  I tried onDoubleTap but I couldn't tell which GridView cell was being tapped so I ended up using OnItemClickListener and onItemLongClick.  Now I know exactly which item in the grid the user selected. Only problem is when I animate it to take up then entire 4x4 grid it does the animation, but I can't figure out how to get it on top.  It seems to go behind all the other cells of the grid.

Comment: Hi, the GridView has a setOnItemClickListener you could have used. As for the View beeing hidden my advice is to put the GridView and one instance of your Framelayouts into a viewFlipper. when a click on the grid occurs you fill the content of the hidden framelayouts and call setDisplayedChild on the ViewFlipper. The animation part can be done by setting an inAnimation and outAnimation on the Viewflipper.